# Prove that $f$ is integrable on any rectangle $R'\subset R$ if $f$ is integrable on $R\subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

If $f$ is integrable on a rectangle $R\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that $f$ is integrable on any rectangle $R'\subset R$.

I tried to prove it in a similar way to prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ so it is on $[a,c]$ and on $[c,d]$ with $c\in[a,b]$. However, i didn't know how to use this fact. I would appreciate any suggestion :)

Comment: Do you know that the product of integrable maps is integrable ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I did not know that :) that would say that all $L^p$ are the same (at least for $p\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and on a finite measure space).

Comment: I don't understand what you said. You said you tried to prove it in a similar way to the way one proves the $1$-dimensional version. Then you said, "I didn't know how to use this fact." What does that mean? Edit your post to include your efforts to do the "similar way." Also, you should clarify: You're talking about the Riemann integral? (That's what the tag says, so I assume yes.)

Comment: If $P$ is a partition, you can refine it so that each partition rectangle is either completely contained in $R'$ or does not intersect, call this partition $P'$. Now estimate $U(f 1_{R'},P')-L(f 1_{R'},P')$ in terms of $U(f,P')-L(f,P')$.